# Make app to get strava data, don't get how to get client_id and client_secret when the user accept to connect to strava

Tags: strava

I am trying to make an app that get strava user info (info, activities, etc...).

I read the instruction of strava doc : https://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/

I get that on my app, I should ask the user to connect to strava using something like : https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=22991&redirect_uri=https://printmyroute.xyz/activity&response_type=code&scope=activity:read_all,read_all,profile:read_all

Then, a connection page appears and then an authorization. When the user accepts the authorization I got a code inside the url. Great! But to follow the doc, to make a request about activities, I need the client_id and client_secret in order to make this request :

```
curl -X POST https://www.strava.com/api/v3/oauth/token \
  -d client_id=ReplaceWithClientID \
  -d client_secret=ReplaceWithClientSecret \
  -d code=ReplaceWithCode \
  -d grant_type=authorization_code
```

But how can I get the client_id and client_secret of the user. (I can make a request using my client_id and client_secret, but this is not the goal, I'd like to access data of the user in order to display it on his app...).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find client ID and client secret in your [application page](https://www.strava.com/settings/api).

`client_id` and `client_secret` are application parameters obtained during registration, they are not connected to user.

Please note that in this request you also use `code` parameter obtained when the user accepts the authorization.

After this request you get a `refresh_token`, which is also specific for the user.

Answer (score 0):

**Spep1 :** Add A app on your Strava Account

**Spep2 :** Using Auth with cliend Id and Scerect code
**Spep3 :** You can refresh your token next use .

[image: you need to add an app in strava]

[image: Then need Auth 2 Authontication]

[image]

**Thanks and happy codding .**